# How to add payload to coap request node-coap

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, coap

I'm using node-coap (https://github.com/mcollina/node-coap) to send Coap packets, now I'm trying to do post or put requests with payload, but I haven't understand how to add payload to request. What method or property I have to use to insert the payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example there in their repo:

https://github.com/mcollina/node-coap/blob/master/examples/req_with_payload.js

```
var req = coap.request('coap://localhost/Matteo')

var payload = {
  title: 'this is a test payload',
  body: 'containing nothing useful'
}

req.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
```